# Select various elements at parent level using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following nested list:

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li class="red"></li>
            <li class="black"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="red"></li>
    <li class="red"></li>
    <li class="black"></li>
</ul>
```

How do I select the elements with the class "red" and "black" that only appear  directly inside the outer  (and not include those inside the nested  tag)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use **>** sign

```
#myList > li.red , #myList > li.black
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/L1yayk74/1/)

and if you just need the red and black inside inner ul

```
#myList ul > li.red , #myList ul > li.black
```

I recommend to read about [Selectors](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#myList>.red ,#myList>.black")
```

">" means son , so the selector "#myList>.red" means the div with id #myList's son(has class red), this will not select grandson 。

"," means join the other selector, by using #myList>.red  you can find two elements, #myList>.black you can also find one .

I guess this is the result you expected. sorry for my poor english. I also recommend you to read about jQuery selector,this is really basic and important .

Comment: at least try and explain what this does.this will not even count as comment.

Comment: ">"  means son  , so the selector "#myList>.red" means the div with id #myList's son(has class red), this will not select grandson  。

Comment: i suggest you add it to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.not()` to select `.red` , `.black` classes that are not child elements of any element

```js
$(".red, .black").not("#myList * *").css("color", "blue")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myList">
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li class="red"></li>
            <li class="black"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="red"></li>
    <li class="red"></li>
    <li class="black"></li>
</ul>
```